# Where are all the puzzle pieces in Hotline Miami?

Tags: hotline-miami

Very similar to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90009/how-do-i-solve-the-puzzle), but I want to know where exactly ALL the puzzle pieces are.

Please provide locations for each puzzle piece in the following format:

- I - Chapter 3, 2nd Floor, Bathroom.

So puzzle letter, chapter its on, and the floor its own. Also please note any ambiguities this format may create for certain pieces (ie, bathroom in the centre if there's multiple bathrooms on that floor).

Comment: This looks like a very broad question. Is there as specific one you are having trouble finding?

Comment: Also important in determining said broadness: How many are there, exactly?

Comment: There are 16 in total. I've only managed to find 3, and they're fairly difficult to spot even with the mask that helps you see them. Would a point list of 16 be too broad? (Something like I - Chapter 2, second floor, bathroom)

Comment: @Jeff That should be doable. It's just a matter of someone finding the time to compile such a list.

Comment: I plan on offering a hefty bounty (hopefully that doesn't deter anyone in the mean time :P

Comment: There are several youtube videos that show where the are. Do you want to know where they are or what the passwords are?

Comment: Where they are, here's video showing them all: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oISmZH6y04  Kinda regretting that bounty now hahaha. Maybe I'll answer my own question. That vid could be better if it were in list form (it does have chapters listed)

Comment: Look at the description of the video and you have your answer.

Comment: I had problem with puzzle pick up. You must stand in place where puzzle is to take it from the ground.

Comment: Yeah they can be a pain to pick up sometimes. I usually end up throwing my weapon. Try standing over them, putting your mouse over them, if you can't get it at first keep trying. The Rasmus mask makes them bounce up and down, so wearing that you can be sure you're on one. In most cases you can clear out the whole level and take your time to pick it up, so it's not that big of a deal. However in the Crackdown level (cahpter 9), you gotta be fast, so this can be a real problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I used this [video extensively](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oISmZH6y04) to figure out each of these. Here they are:

- U - Prelude: *The Metro*. 1st Floor, Bottom Left end of the tracks
- T - Chapter 1: *No Talk*. 2nd Floor, Top left kitchen in front of sink
- A - Chapter 2: *Overdose*. 2nd Floor, Bottom Right bathroom (between toilet and tub)
- O - Chapter 3: *Decadence*. 2nd Floor, Bottom Left dining room in front of chair (furthest right, top row)
- A - Chapter 4: *Tension*. 2nd Floor, Bombroom (left below window)
- E - Chapter 5: *Full House*. 1st Floor, Bottom right kitchen (right of top chair)
- I - Chapter 6: *Clean Hit*. 2nd Floor, Bottom right balcony (below head of lower patio chair)
- N - Chapter 7: *Neighbours*. 1st Floor, Top Left Bedroom, right of computer chair.
- R - Chapter 8: *Push It*. Right 2nd Floor, Top right corner of top right dance floor
- S - Chapter 9: *Crackdown*. 2nd Floor. Top middle by elevator? BE FAST, you have to be the SWAT
- I - Chapter 10: *Hot-N-Heavy*. (Top right floor), bottom left pool room, below bottom pool chair

Spoilers:

> Jake is also found in this chapter, on a dead body in the uppermost room of the top floor

- N - Chapter 11: *Deadline*. 2nd Floor, Bottom Left
- W - Chapter 12: *Trauma*. Starting Floor, bottom right bathroom next to toilet.
- S - Chapter 13: *Assault*. 1st Floor, Bottom Left bathroom (between toilet and "sink" (I think it may be one of those sinks you wash your bum with, but I don't think they're common in Miami? (they're not in Canada...)))
- B - Chapter 14: *Vengenace*. 3rd Floor, Bathroom in front of stairs (upper left urinal)
- H - Final Chapter: *Showdown*. 1st floor, room on the left between coach and chair.

> This spells out IWASBORNINTHEUSA, which is the password to the computer in Chapter 19. It seems to changed the dialog if you view the computer before you talk to the guys